# is there another way other than livequery to add jquery buttun and date picker from ajax?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

i used livequery for jq ui buttun and date picker

it is so slooooow

is there an alternative **like the new on() method**

or something that is *fast for large documents*

please help i am stuck and the pages not responding

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery's built in [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method? or try using the [`.delegate()`](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/) method.

Comment: well nothing worked so i loaded parts of my pages with ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to look into:

- `.delegate()` (for slightly older jQuery, 1.7 and less) or `.on()` for newer versions *(`.live()` is deprecated)*
- Manually setting the event handling in the "success" function of your ajax-call. This is particularly useful if you event handling needs to change based on what your ajax-call returns.

Without more detail, I cannot help you more.

Comment: Do you have some references for `live()` being deprecated? I'm a few versions behind in most of my projects.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/live/ (below version 1.4.3; .live() is the only option, but I would suggest updating jQuery in that case, as there have been some major improvements since then)

Comment: this is good :) 
can you please give me an example how to bind events to the returned data from the ajax call 
and can i do it in .ajaxComplete() function for all my calls

Comment: Well that depends a lot on what you are returning and how you are returning it, I need more specifics before I can elaborate. .AjaxComplete is not the same as doing something in the Success function of an ajax call. http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/ If you run Ajaxcomplete, you will always execute the same function on one specific element. For example a div used for logging all in- and outgoing ajaxcalls. If you want to do an ajax call, receive data, then manipulate the data before putting it on the page, the 'success' function of an Ajax call is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `live()` method. As you can see here http://jsperf.com/jquery-live-vs-delegate-vs-on the live method beats `on()` and `delegate()`

Comment: Doubtful. .live() has been deprecated for a while now. Your own example page has my tests running faster for delegate() and on() (no real difference between the two). This is true for FF, IE and Chrome so I would strongly advise against using .live()